# Find out if item exists in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Styles collection

Tags: c#, com, interop, styles

I'm trying to access an item on the Styles collection of a word document, I was wondering if there's a way to know if an item with a given key exists without it throwing an exception.

Right now I'm doing something like:

```
newStyle = _document.Styles.get_Item(ref styleName);
```

This works when the item exists, if it doesn't it will fail (I know that I can use a try/catch block but I would prefer not to.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Never use 2 dots with COM objects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects-in-c/158752#158752

Comment: Are you able to loop through the Styles collection? If so, that might be the only way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over the styles and check the name, and exit the loop if you have a match.